# Как разбить файл на несколько по буквам?

Tags: python

Есть большой файл в формате txt/csv с полями:
Имя;Email;Статус

Как можно разбить этот файл по буквам?

```
А.txt - все имена с буквы А.
Б.txt - все имена с буквы Б.
и т.д.
```

Comment: построчно разбираете csv, те строки у которых поля начинаются на А, кладёте в А.txt и т.д... в чем проблема? в чтении CSV? в записи файла? в итерации строк? с составлении условия?..  Вы пытались самостоятельно решить данную задачу? можно увидеть код вашим попыток?

Comment: Откуда вас, лентяев, опять столько повылезало?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

1. Загрузите CSV в DataFrame `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`
2. Отсортируйте по столбцу df.sort_values(by=['Имя'])
3. Сгруппируйте df по первой букве того же столбца и разбейте его на словари, кортежи или списки датафреймов. Используйте groupby, tolist или generator expressions.
4. Запишите полученную коллекцию в файлы.